# CSS Bootstrap - delete margin left

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Thank you in advance

I am developping a .NET responsive web-page with an image and a gridview.

I am trying to delete a "margin-left:auto" property defined in "grid.less" bootstrap file with no success.
I have already tried "margin-left:0px", left:0px, with no success also. 
That's how my page is:
[image: Page (sorry but i can't put the image in the post)]

ASP.NET:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="global">
        <div class="itemwrapper">
            <img src="Content/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive"  />
        </div>
  (...)
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   max-width: 1050px;
   margin: 60px auto 60px auto;
  }
.global {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
  }
.itemwrapper {
  margin-left:0px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: "[The margin property] applies to all elements except elements with table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table. In other words, the margin property is not applicable to display:table-cell elements." And you say Bootstrap and you don't use it in your HTML markup.

Comment: Hi! I am trying to "remove" the margin in image and not in my table.

Comment: It seems like your image doesn't have a margin (there is nothing in your code about that). I applied your code and there is no margin https://codepen.io/makshh/pen/XRYdKp

Comment: Hello. Well, you are rigth. I mean, the space between the start of the page and the start of the image. Do you understand? My mistake, sorry

Comment: Yep, that's because you set `max-width` to your `.wrapper`. Remove it and set `width: 100%` or change margin to `margin: 60px 0;`.

Comment: yey! Thank you! That solved my problem! 
Now i have another problem: Since i have "display:table-cell" to have both divs horizontally, the image is not "so responsive" as if i delete that line, but i need it to have the 2 divs displayed horizontally. 
Do you know how to solve this? Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

With just the code that you provided, I think you could try this code:

```
.wrapper {
   max-width: 1050px;
   margin: 60px 0;
 }
```

Instead of:

```
.wrapper {
   max-width: 1050px;
   margin: 60px auto 60px auto;
 }
```